# Ways to integrate spring MVC with Restful web services

Tags: spring, rest, model-view-controller

I am trying to understand Spring MVC Restful architecture. Want to know how many ways are there to integrate spring MVC with Restful web services. I can see one of it is using Rest Template.

Is it the only way to use rest web services in Spring MVC.

Can we develop web application using spring MVC alone without consuming any web services.

Please correct me if am wrong .

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring MVC is a framework and does not always require web services to develop web application.

A web service is a function that can be accessed by other programs over the web (Http or in simple words any piece of software that makes itself available over the internet and uses a standardized messaging system.

So, if you want to communicate with another application which either exposes or consume web service then you will integrate web service in your application.

Rest Template is one of the best ways to work with Restful webservice.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other way to integrate Restful web service with Spring MVC other than Rest Template.

Comment: For Spring Template Documentation : by default the RestTemplate relies on standard JDK facilities to establish HTTP connections. You can switch to use a different HTTP library such as Apache HttpComponents, Netty, and OkHttp through the InterceptingHttpAccessor.setRequestFactory(org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactory) property.